# Dockerized API returns socket hang up via Postman

Tags: .net, docker, postman

I've created simple RestAPI in .net core 5.0 - it has only one job, return StatusCode 200 or 500:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("checktrue")]
    public IActionResult HealthCheckTrue()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("checkfalse")]
    public IActionResult HealthCheckFalse()
    {
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

When im building it locally, everything works fine, but as soon as I'm hosting it in docker container, I cannot reach it with Postman.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["HealthCheck/HealthCheck.csproj", "HealthCheck/"]
RUN dotnet restore "HealthCheck/HealthCheck.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/HealthCheck"
RUN dotnet build "HealthCheck.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HealthCheck.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HealthCheck.dll"]
```

When I run docker container it starts normally:

```
=info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:80

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

Hosting environment: Production

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

Content root path: /app
```

(Port is mapped to 5020)
I'm sending the request:
http://localhost:5020/api/checktrue and I get Error: socker hang up

When I'm doing the same request on my machine it works fine.

Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. Try to call your endpoint `http://localhost:5020/api/checktrue` with [cURL](https://curl.se/).

The [cURL](https://curl.se/) tool gave me a more telling answer than the Postman did.

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

The error could be caused if [cURL](https://curl.se/) is asked to do plain `HTTP` on a server that does `HTTPS`.

Your **.NET API** in the container probably is listening on port **80** and also **443**. Even if `launchsettings.json` says differently. This setting don't change the startup for the `Docker container` actually.

My sollution was to set default URL with Kestrel configuration in the **Program.cs** class.

In **.NET5** it would be like

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:80");
            });
```

In **.NET6** the **UserUrls()** method is not using anymore, it will look as follow.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//...

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(80);
});

//...

var app = builder.Build();
```